# Gulp 4.0.1. Модуль 'del' не найден

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp4

Столкнулся с проблемой: при сборке проекта в Gulp версии 4.0.1 не получается использовать модуль 'del'. Терминал выдает следующее: 'ReferenceError: del is not defined'. Но модуль я установил командой 'npm i del -D' и в package.json он есть.

```
{
  "name": "testgulp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^4.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

И соответственно gulpfile:

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const clear = require('del');

gulp.task('clear', function() {
    return del.sync(['dist']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка значит, что переменная del не определена.

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const del= require('del');

gulp.task('clear', function() {
    return del.sync(['dist']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В документации, вот тут https://www.npmjs.com/package/del четко прописано что теперь писать нужно не: import del from 'del'; а по другому, вот так: import {deleteAsync} from 'del';

В файле reset.js пишем:

```
import {deleteAsync} from 'del';
export const reset = () => {
    return deleteAsync(app.path.clean);
}
```

И в файле package.json меняем строчку вот на эту:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^7.0.0"
  }
```

Актуально на 10.10.2022

И да прибудет с вам счастье, друзья!!!